# Layering 3.6 new Geonodes hair system in one object

Tags: geometry-nodes, rigid-body-simulation, hair

I'm trying to have short hairs and Long straggly hairs on an object. When people have been layering hair it seems to create a second object. I'm trying to avoid this as I would like to use this tennis ball as a rigid body simulation. Maybe something is wrong with my workflow.

My process, model the object, Add the first fur/hair system and tweak it, then duplicate the object with another system and hide the object (Which has sometimes created black marks). Having these parts makes it so much harder to put into a simulation.

[image]

[image]

Here are some pictures to visualise what I'm dealing with. I think the hair is so much better in the new system rather than the particle hair emitter. So maybe there is a way to compile it all into one object and achieve this.

I have gone through a lot of hair system tutorials but can't find exactly what I'm looking for, any help would be greatly appreciated!